# Remove diacritics, except for certain diacritics on certain letters

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, diacritics

I'm trying to remove Hebrew diacritics. I need to remove all diacritics, except for given diacritics, coming after given letters.

This is my non-working `RemoveDiacritics` (see [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mUO6Wk)):

```
public static string RemoveDiacritics(Dictionary<char, char[]> exclude, string source)
{
    // Exclude letters (using a lookbehind), include diacritics
    string match = "(?<=[א-ת])[\u05b0-\u05c2]";    

    // Prepare the exclusion group
    string exclusionGroup = string.Join("|", exclude.Select(p => 
         string.Concat(p.Key, string.Join(string.Empty, p.Value)))
    );

    // Create the exclusion group (using a lookahead)
    string except = $"(?!{exclusionGroup})";

    // Do the match
    return Regex.Replace(source, string.Concat(except, match), string.Empty);
}
```

I tested it with:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string source = "חָזִיתִי כְּמִבַּעַד לֶעָשָׁן בְּקִמּוּרֵי הָרֶסֶס הַלָּבָן";
    Dictionary<char, char[]> exclude = new Dictionary<char, char[]>
    {
        {'\u05db', new char[] {'\u05bc' } }, // כּ
        {'\u05d1', new char[] {'\u05bc', '\u05b7' } }, // בַּ
    };
    string replaced = RemoveDiacritics(exclude, source);
}
```

Expected result: `"חזיתי כּמבַּעד לעשן בקמורי הרסס הלבן"` (only 2 letters on the 2nd word should have diacritics).

Actual result: `"חזיתי כְמִבַעד לעשָן בְקמורי הרסס הלָבן"`

In my actual result, you can see that:

1. Any letter that had `'\u05bc'` (it's that little dot *inside* a letter) together with an additional diacritic, is wrongly left with that additional diacritic.
2. Also, there are diacritics left on `מִ` and `שָ` (they are on the 2nd & 3rd word, respectively). No clue why.

How can I make it work?

Comment: as a first step, I'd debug-output the runtime value of `exclusionGroup` and test the resulting regex

Comment: @dlatikay, I get the expected result, which is `(?!כּ|בַּ)`, and that's what I need (or do I?).

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove all diacritics but some after some letters?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, that's correct.

Comment: Then, try something like `@"(what_you_need_to_keep)|\p{M}+"` and replace with `$1`.

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are doing, could you please explain step by step? I used hex notation for your diacritics and letters and your resulting regex looks like `(?!\u05db\u05bc|\u05d1\u05bc\u05b7)(?<=[\u05D0-\u05EA])[\u05b0-\u05c2]`. Do you really want to use the letters in a lookbehind? What are those exclusion combinations? Trying to follow the logic, I tried https://ideone.com/biqXcS, but it does not seem to yield the expected result.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I tried your suggestion and [it seems like an improvement](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jLkwma) - it removes all diacritics, but also the targeted letters (together with their target diacritics). Your hex values are correct. To use your phrasing, I need all diacritics (and *only* diacritics, which is why I used non-diacritics in the lookbehind), but some after some letters (those that are placed inside the lookahead).

Comment: You messed my code a bit in your latest fiddle. You must replace with `$1`. `string leaveOnly = String.Concat(String.Format(@"({0})|\p{{M}}+", exclusionGroup));
  return Regex.Replace(source, leaveOnly, "$1");`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, your'e right, and now [it works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pYvmRJ)! Please post it as an answer. I'd like to understand this regex pattern (and if you know why, also why mine didn't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RemoveDiacritics` method should look like

```
public static string RemoveDiacritics(Dictionary<char, char[]> exclude, string source)
{
    string exclusionGroup = string.Join("|", exclude.Select(p => string.Concat(p.Key, string.Join(string.Empty, p.Value))));
    string leaveOnly = String.Concat(String.Format(@"({0})|\p{{M}}+", exclusionGroup));
    return Regex.Replace(source, leaveOnly, "$1");
}
```

What it does is:

- `exclusionGroup` is created from the `exclude` chars and this is just an alternation sequence
- `leaveOnly` is the regex pattern, its form is `(<what_you_need_to_keep>)|\p{M}+` that matches and *captures* what you need to keep (ignore) into Group 1 and just matches any 1+ diacritics using `\p{M}+` pattern.
- The replacement pattern is the palceholder to Group 1 value, `$1`, to restore it in the resulting string.

Here is an [online C# demo](https://ideone.com/49cRAN).

Comment: @HeyJude From what I understood it did not match all diacritics, and the negative lookahead and positive lookbehind were executed in the same place inside the string.